# Ruby regular expression to "go until blank line"

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following test string:

```
puts "Wrong guess receives feedback"
p (game.guess(11) == "Too high!")

puts "Wrong guess deducts from remaining guesses"
p (game.remaining_guesses == 3)
```

In english I'm trying to:

```
capture everything after "puts " 
until you get to a blank line
(aka beginning of a string followed immediately by end of string)
```

I know how to "go until you run into something". Like for example, "go until you run into a double quote"

```
[6] pry(main)> re = /[^"]+/
=> /[^"]+/
[7] pry(main)> "stuff before a quote\"".slice(re)
=> "stuff before a quote"
```

I think `re = /^$/` will "capture a blank line"
http://rubular.com/r/E5F7wH6sNq

So How would I go about capturing "everything after 'puts ' and until you get to a blank line"? I've tried the following:

```
re = /puts ([^^$]+)/
```

But it didn't work: http://rubular.com/r/yUhA090fLm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str.scan /(?<=puts ).*?(?=\R\R|\z)/m                                                                                                           
#⇒ [
#    [0] "\"Wrong guess receives feedback\"\np (game.guess(11) == \"Too high!\")",
#    [1] "\"Wrong guess deducts from remaining guesses\"\np (game.remaining_guesses == 3)"
# ]
```

Positive lookbehind `puts`, followed by non-greedy anything till two carriage returns / blank lines (note that `\R` captures the latter on *any platform*, including Win and MacOS,) or the end of input.

Comment: I had no idea about `\R`. Good one!

Answer (score 1):

This would be one way to do it:

```
re = /puts (.*?)\r?\n\r?\n/m
```

`.*` means "zero or more of any character except newlines". I'll explain the `?` later.

The `m` (for "multiline") modifier at the end makes it mean "zero or more of any character including newlines".

The `\r?\n\r?\n` is two newlines in a row, accounting for the fact that it can be represented differently on different systems. You could replace this part with `$^` instead, but then the `(.*?)` will end up contain a trailing newline, because the `$` for "end of line" matches after a newline, not before.

The `?` makes `.*` "lazy" – it matches as little as possible, instead of being "greedy" and matching as much as possible. This is relevant if you have multiple blank lines: you presumably don't want it to greedily match "zero or more of any character until the very last blank line"; you want it to lazily match "zero or more of any character until the first blank line".

One of the problems with your `/puts ([^^$]+)/` is that `[^abc]` is effectively a shortcut for "any one character that isn't a, b or c". It doesn't mean "not an 'a' followed by a 'b' followed by a 'c'".

Comment: The above will fail on Windows.

Comment: For Rails2+ there is `\R` matcher.